# Preloading data in memory and sharing among Python Flask processes/workers

Tags: python, flask, shared-memory

I was wondering if there's a way to preload a huge shared readonly data structure, when launching a flask server in production (i.e. using gunicorn or another WSGI HTTP server). This data loading process takes too much time if I do this at every request, so I need to preload and provide to my clients all the information they need about this.
What is the correct, performant and best practice way of doing this?

Here are some details how my current server code looks like:

1. It reads a huge file and builds a dictionary list at the beginning of the server script execution.
2. This structure acts like a global readonly resource all over the server scripts.
3. The resource file consists of a set of huge shapefile structures which are loaded in memory.
4. It works fine when in debug mode by running using the python interpreter, maybe because it only instantiates the data only once.
5. When running with gunicorn it gets incredible slow and also may crash and I even can't use other workers, otherwise they will consume all the volatile memory resource.

Simplifying, my server script code looks like this:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
import serverinfo
import api

app = Flask(__name__.split('.')[0])

@app.route("/api/getinfo/<coordinates>", methods=['GET'])
def getinfo(coordinates):
    for m in api.MAPS:
        if check_collision(coordinates, m):
            return jsonify(m['details']), 200
    return jsonify({'err' : 'no results'}), 400

#... other stuff

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host=serverinfo.host, port=serverinfo.port)
```

The api.__init__.py looks like this:

```
import pickle

#... other stuff

def load_maps():
    maps = []
    with open(MAPPATH, "rb") as box_file:
        box_res = pickle.load(box_file)
        for res in box_res:
            m = Map(*res)
            maps.append(m)
    return maps

#... other stuff

MAPS = load_maps()
```